# Virtual Environment in Debian with different Python version

Tags: python, linux, debian, virtualenv

I want to create virtual environment using python 3.9.15 version. It will get the global version of python but not that version in virtual environment. can you suggest me solution for that

I tried to do using venv and virtualenv but it didn't work.

Comment: Try using pipenv, it works pretty predictably https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `pipenv`, it works predictably for me (and for my team)

https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/

A sample Pipfile looks like this

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
fastapi = {extras = ["httpx"], version = "==0.92.0"}
uvicorn = {extras = ["standard"], version = "==0.20.0"}
pydantic = "==1.10.4"


[dev-packages]
invoke = "==1.4.1"


[requires]
python_version = "3.9"
python_full_version = "3.9.15"
```

You need to create a `Pipfile` with the version of Python that you want in your project directory, and then run
`pipenv install`

This will install the virtual env with the Python version that you specified and all the packages in the file.

Then you can access the virtual environment shell by using `pipenv shell`.

You can read more in their docs: https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe -m venv venv
```

You have to go to the path of python 3.9.15 version copy that path(in my case `C:\Users\kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\` this is the path, after that add python.exe -m venv venv , It will create virtual environment with the python version 3.9.15